# How to stop a quick appearance of unstyled content from displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following site where there is a quick flash of the site with the megamenu-new.css not affecting the site.

Here is the url: http://test.foulston.com/about

You can click back and fourth between about and careers pages to see the flash. I have tried what other people have suggested, but nothing is working.

The issue started after we applied the Adobe Accessible Mega Menu to the site.

If anyone can suggest how to fix this I would be grateful.

Comment: What have you tried already? Without knowing people may provide solutions that you've already tried the implement.

Comment: Check out whether this link helps: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/web-designer/how-to-prevent-flash-of-unstyled-content-on-your-websites/